# subgit timeout waiting for pid file

Tags: docker, gitlab, subgit

I have GitLab on docker container and I tried to use SubGit. Synchronization from SVN to Git working good, but I have problem when i try to do git push. I get the following error and the daemon.pid file is deleted from subgit directory.

```
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: SubGit ERROR REPORT (SubGit version 3.2.2 ('Bobique') build #3603):        
remote: 
remote: You've received this message because SubGit (http://subgit.com/) is installed in your repository        
remote: and an error that needs to be dealt with has occurred in SubGit translation engine.        
remote: 
remote: TEMPORARY ERROR:        
remote:  Failed to launch background translation process: timeout waiting for pid file '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lpp/OA.git/./subgit/daemon.pid'.        
remote: 
remote: CURRENT STATE:        
remote:  Both Git and Subversion repository are open for pushes or commits.        
remote:  Your commit was not committed, but you may retry it.        
remote: 
remote: TO RECOVER:        
remote:    A) Address the problem if possible and then retry commit        
remote:  OR        
remote:    B) Run on the server        
remote:       $ subgit uninstall /var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lpp/OA.git/.        
remote: 
remote:  IMPORTANT: As soon as SubGit is uninstalled, both Git and Subversion repositories        
remote:             will become open, but no synchronization will take place.        
remote: 
remote: TO REPORT:        
remote:  Report an issue at ...        
remote:  You may find logs on the server at '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/lpp/OA.git/./subgit/logs'        
remote: 
remote: THANK YOU!        
error: failed to push some refs to ...
Not all refs have been pushed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i run subgit configure/install inside container (docker exec -it container-name bash) then files owner was correct (git) and everything is good now :)